# C++ convert float to long int using std::llround

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion, integer, integer-overflow

I am trying to convert float value to long long int, using std::llround. But there seems to have some precision or "overflow" issue. I am not sure.  The code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float value = 123456.0f;

    value *= 1.0E+6f;

    std::cout << value << std::endl; // 1.23456e+11

    std::cout << "after rounding: " << std::llround(value) << std::endl; // 123455995904

    return;
}
```

The float value is 1.23456e+11, but using std::cout, the converted integer looks like 123455995904. I would expect it to be something like '123456000000'. How can I achieve that?

If I do the rounding directly on double value :

```
std::cout << "rounding double: " << std::llround(123456000000.0) << std::endl;
```

Then the long integer becomes expected: 123456000000.

(I am using Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10.)
Many thanks!

Comment: The full name of `float` datatype is "single-precision floating point" and `double` is "double-precision floating point".  You should not be surprised that the precision is less for `float` than `double`...

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your comment. Do you mean the "some" precision is lost during the rounding process/computation, when using float?

Comment: This value is unrepresentable in `float`. You can see it e.g. with `std::cout << std::fixed << value` and for instance check the output for `value = (value - 0.01f) * 1.0E+6f` it will be the same as for `value * 1.0E+6f`.

Comment: @David: The multiplication `123456.0f * 1.0E+6f` computes and stores the result to single precision (it stores the nearest value, representable in a `float`, to the true result).  That nearest representable value is 123455995904

Comment: For the record: float can accurately represent integers up to about 2^24.  Your value closer to 2^37

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks a lot for the link to the other answer. It does explain a lot.